# 301 redirect .php to non-php page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Currently, my site is set up to redirect a .php to a non-php version.  Problem with this is when I checked, it is issuing a "200 OK" for both pages, which I know is a no no with google.

I want to 301 redirect the .php page to the non-php.  It is the same page, and I have already added the canonical link to the page, reflecting the non-.php page.

How do I set up the 301?  I am currently handling the .php to direct to non-.php page using .htaccess with the following code:

```
# Remove filename extension
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas how to resolve the 200 OK to 301 redirect the .php page (note they are the same page)?

Answer (score 2):

You need one additional rule:

```
# Remove filename extension
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Place this rule before your existing rule.

This will externally redirect all `.php` file to non `.php` version. Thus Google will not index your `.php` file.

Comment: can you resend with the entire block of code with how it should look?  I am not completely understanding where it needs to go?  thank you

Comment: thank you.  i just tried to implement and it did not work. some files are located in a directory, others not...does that matter?

Comment: YES!  It worked.  Thank you very much.  You have been a great help!

Comment: Since I have you here, do you know how to redirect to all lowercase in .htaccess for any url?

Comment: I am using .htaccess not http.confd.  I wasnt sure i understood the condition that all CSS files need to be "/".

Comment: i am sorry.  i am a novice with this stuff...is there anyway you can show me the code and where to apply it?

Comment: I already have code in my linked answer. That is all you need to do. Also since this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468946/rewrite-rule-in-htaccess-convert-query-string-into-slashes-php/43471053#43471053

Comment: Please review at @anubhava

Comment: When I am trying to add this code, it successfully works without .php but when someone is coming from social media, it adds some parameters and it doesn't load resources. I mean the page loads broken. Do we have any solution for this? Or if we try to add a / after the url like example.com/contact/ it doesn't work. It just works when the URL is like example.com/contact