# Rewrite Rule in htaccess convert query string into slashes php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK I've tried multiple solutions but still can't achieve it. so what I need to do is

```
mydomain.com/search?q=product&l=london
```

**to**

```
mydomain.com/search/product/london
```

Basically I'm using rewrite rules to hide .php extension by following this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So now, search.php converts into search and when user searches. it redirects to trailing slash instead of query string

Here what I've used so far

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search/?q=([^&]+)&l=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [NC,L,R]

#skip the rule if the request is for dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 #skip the rule if the request is for file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #rewrite any other request  to "/packagemenu.php?"
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search?q=$1&l=$2 [NC,L]
```

AND

```
RewriteBase /search/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+)&l=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search?q=$1&l=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But both of them doesn't work. I don't have so much knowledge about so please help me out.

Comment: I think it's a silly mistake since you have GET variable _location_ but searching for `l` in regex.

Comment: it is l. sorry i need to edit Get variable is q and l

Comment: Does `search.php` exist at the same level as .htaccess and are both in your website root?

Comment: yes @anubhava that's why search.php become only search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your site root .htaccess as this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jobportal/

# To externally redirect /search.php?q=product&l=london to /search/query/london/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+)&l=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /search.php?q=product to /search/query/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/? [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# ignore all rules below for real files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal forward from /search/product/ to search.php?q=product
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# internal forward from /search/product/london/ to search.php?q=product&l=london
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&l=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# internal forward from /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Nope it is not like that. and it doesn't work my .htaccess has first RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: then there is no rule

Comment: You are so near bruh. Just it redirects to http://localhost/search/hello/adjk/ instead of http://localhost/jobportal/search/hello/adjk/ Can you please look at it

Comment: and the second issue is when i click search button it still makes such kind of url mydomain.com/search?q=product&l=london instead of mydomain.com/search/product/london Please help me I have very limited information on htaccess

Comment: It is redirecting but it says Object not found have a look at image http://imgur.com/G5G8Mv8

Comment: Oh man thank you so much it works now. It redirects too. but just need to ask a little can you please explain it I want to make another rule. how would i do it ?

Comment: And on hosting it redirects to /home/requwrzc/public_html/ despite i set it my base_path

Comment: I've added a comment above each of the rules. If `RewriteBase` is defined then you shouldn't get `/home/requwrzc/public_html/` after redirection.

Comment: I set the rewrite base by getting __Dir__ but it still shows me the same

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem on any of my Apache versions and we cannot make wild guess why that might be happening. You can just make redirect URL absolute as this: `RewriteRule ^ /jobportal/search/%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: Ok I will try thanks for your assistance and If i need to do with 1 query string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the URL `mydomain.com/search/product/london` by using the following rule in your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search?q=$1&l=$2 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Nope doesn't work it is still redirecting to search?q=product&l=london.

I cleared my cache and run it in incognito too but doesn't work

Comment: Very strange @SaadSuri ... is the above your entire `.htaccess` contents? As it sounds like one of your other rules is causing your rewrite to break.

Comment: No it is below one rewrite rule where I'm hiding .php extension and that rule is mentioned above

Comment: and you've tried putting the rule above the one for removing .php?

Comment: Nope the order of rewrite rule is no.1) Rule for hiding .php 2) your given method

Comment: Even I tried this alone too by using RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search,php/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search,php?q=$1&l=$2 [L] still it doesn't work

Comment: @thickguru I think they are looking for the opposite ... `/search?q=product&l=london` is the originally requested URL, presumably invoked by submitting a search form. They want to rewrite that so to the “pretty” URL `/search/product/london` shows in the browser address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^\/]+)&l=([^\/]+)$
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^search/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)$ search.php?q=$1&l=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: what is the error I didn't saw your full .htaccess make sure that no other rule is conflicting.

Comment: It is working now but How could i redirect like when i type localhost/jobportal/search?q=hello&l=london. It automatically redirects to http://localhost/jobportal/search/hello/london

Comment: Or when I click search It redirects me to 
localhost/jobportal/search/hello/london

Comment: Sadly, It doesn't work too. It now also doesn't work with  localhost/jobportal/search/hello/london giving error object not found

Comment: Try now I tested it on my side!

Comment: Please have a look It is not redirecting the only problem I'm facing http://imgur.com/PKBSZjp

Comment: Well, where are you using the rules I am assuming you are using them in jobportal directory.

Comment: Yes absolutely.